# Data get repeated with json_arrayagg

Tags: mysql, sql

The output getting from the query id repeated it the data inside is multiple

```
select json_arrayagg(json_object("network", basics_profiles.network, "username", basics_profiles.username, "url", basics_profiles.url)) as profiles from basics_profiles;
```

Ok here when i run this code  the in work section even when there it is only 2 data. it get doubled. if there was only single data. then there is no issue.

output while there is more tan 1 data:

```
[
    {
        "url": "twitter.com/naruto",
        "network": "Twitter",
        "username": "uzumakinaruto"
    },
    {
        "url": "twitter.com/naruto",
        "network": "Twitter",
        "username": "uzumakinaruto"
    },
    {
        "url": "instagram.com/naruto",
        "network": "Instagram",
        "username": "uzumakinaruto"
    },
    {
        "url": "instagram.com/naruto",
        "network": "Instagram",
        "username": "uzumakinaruto"
    }
]
```

i wanted something like this

```
[
    {
        "url": "twitter.com/naruto",
        "network": "Twitter",
        "username": "uzumakinaruto"
    },
    {
        "url": "instagram.com/naruto",
        "network": "Instagram",
        "username": "uzumakinaruto"
    }
]
```

u can try with the thsi table:

```
create table basics_profiles(network text, url text, username text);

insert into basics_profiles values("twitter","jhaajdka.com","naruto");

insert into basics_profiles values("instagram","jhasdasdasdsdd.com","sasuke");
```

Comment: the work filed gives the output as the second comment . by doubling the same data.

Comment: Please do not (directly) comment on your own question. you should use [edit] for that.

Comment: Fix the tags, MySQL is completely different from PostgreSQL.  Only use the tag for the DBMS that you are actually using (including version numbering because of the differences between MySQL/MariaDB)

Comment: Some sample (input) data, to have a [mre], would be nice!

Comment: Thanks for doing the edits. Unfortunate with the given data it is not possible to reproduce the problem, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Helping me out. i got my issue. With the about code it was showing all the data in a single row if i had multiple row of data, for me the issue was when joining 2 tables the data get repeated again and again.

```
select 
   basics_information.*,
   (select json_arrayagg(json_object("name", interests.name, "keywords", interests.keywords)) 
    from interests 
    where basics_information.id = interests.resumeId) as interests 
from basics_information 
left join interests on basics_information.id = interests.resumeId 
group by basics_information.id;
```

Comment: The query in the question doesn't have a join.

Answer (score 0):

With the given info, you could try (could not test because of missing input data):

```
select 
   json_arrayagg(DISTINCT json_object("network", basics_profiles.network, 
                             "username", basics_profiles.username, 
                             "url", basics_profiles.url)
                ) as profiles 
from basics_profiles;
```

EDIT:

- With MariaDB 10.6 the DISTINCT is not even needed, see: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=8540165242a760689afdeadcfb521d88)
- With MySQL8.0 the DISTINCT is not even needed, see: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8540165242a760689afdeadcfb521d88)

**This proves that input data is needed to reproduce the problem**

Comment: thanks.. this thing works. i dont understand where is my codes issue.

Comment: It might have to do with versions? What is the output of this: `select version();` ?

Comment: 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3